# Deployment Failed

Tags: aws-codepipeline

**How to solve Deployment failed issues?**

"The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are experiencing problems. (Error code: HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS)"

I am trying to create Code Pipeline for building and staging application.
I used code commit as a source ,code build as builder, and code deploy for deploy my code. I have installed code deploy agent on instance but still I am getting above issue.
please let me know solution.

Comment: You need to check the log files.  There should be something in them to explain the failed deployments of the instances it is talking about.

Answer (score 0):

In code deploy log you can exactly know what might be the reason. My thought is may be you have configured code-deploy to roll back when alarm thresholds are met, please check the configuration and your alarm thresholds.

[image: code-deploy rollback configurations]

If you attach the log with question it will be easy to answer.